# Load image from resource not working on windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, path, separator

why isn't this working on windows but on mac?

```
public final static String PATH = "resources" + File.separator;

/** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
public static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String name, String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = GuiTools.class.getResource(PATH + name);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + PATH + name);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer that worked best, by clicking the Green checkbox next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because File.separator is the system dependent character for files, which is "/" for mac but "\" for windows.  However, in a URL, all of the separators should be '/'.  Try changing the first line to be:

```
public final static String PATH = "resources/";
```

Comment: Thats what I thought first too but it did not fix it.

Comment: How are you running java in each environment?  From the same directory?  Is your classpath set the same in both cases?  Can you post the actual commands you are running to start java, and make sure you are running it from the same relative directory.

Comment: Yes, it is the same file I start without parameters with java -jar Test.jar